# Kill another app and all its services programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, kill-process

I'm creating an app that turns on another application whenever the user gets a phone call and turns that application off when the phone call ends.

This is my code:

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
    final String PROXIMITY_SERVICE_PACKAGE_NAME = "package_name";

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String state = extras.getString( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE );

    if (state.equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING ) ) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        context.startActivity( packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                PROXIMITY_SERVICE_PACKAGE_NAME ) );
    }

    if ( state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE ) ) {
        killProcess(context, PROXIMITY_SERVICE_PACKAGE_NAME);
    }
}
```

The killProcess method is currently implemented this way:

```
private void killProcess(Context context, String packageName)
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
}
```

I also ask for permission to kill background applications in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

The opening of the app is working, but the closing of the app doesn't. 
I know I reach the code in killProcess, but it doesn't kill the app. 
Is this a problem with permissions? Am I not allowed to kill another process? not even a process I created?

Or maybe, from what I know about the process I'm running, it creates a service that does all the work for it. Maybe the problem is that the service does not terminate?

Is there any way to terminate this process and all the services and sub processes that are related to it (like for example when you do FORCE STOP in settings)?

Thanks.

Comment: No way you can kill any other app process but yours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can kill any process.

1. Find the app process ID
2. Kill it.

Once you have the app process ID, just pass in this function:

```
Process.killProcess( APP-PROCESS-ID )
```

Note that the process class, should be imported from Android:

```
import android.os.Process
```

You can also try this if you know the package name of the app:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses("app-package-name");
```